# MySQL GROUP BY all columns except of one

Tags: mysql, group-by

I need to compare two tables with exactly the same fields/types and identify all records which are different in at least one field or do only exist in one of the two tables.

Both tables have an column `id` with a unique value for each record. This would allow to identify corresponding records in both tables. But it does not mean, that those records are identical (any of the other columns can be different between the two records).

```
table0:

| id | col1 | col2 | ... |
| -- | ---- | ---- | --- |
| 22 | 1111 | 'gt' | ... |
| 23 | 5624 | 'ha' | ... |
| 24 | 7775 | 'oh' | ... |
| 26 | 2113 | 'yh' | ... |
| 28 | 9988 | 'wq' | ... |

table1:

| id | col1 | col2 | ... |
| -- | ---- | ---- | --- |
| 22 | 1111 | 'gt' | ... |
| 23 | 5624 | 'ha' | ... |
| 25 | 3333 | 'er' | ... |
| 26 | 2113 | 'ya' | ... |
| 28 | 9988 | 'wq' | ... |

What I need is the following result/output:

| id | reason |
| -- | ------ |
| 24 | only in table0 |
| 25 | only in table1 |
| 26 | not identical values |
```

A simple way would obviously be

```
SELECT *
    FROM
    (
        SELECT *, 0 AS src /* added src to identify table 0 */
        FROM table0
        UNION ALL
        SELECT *, 1 AS src /* added src to identify table 1 */
        FROM table1
    )  temp
    GROUP BY col1, col2, col3, ...
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

But there are two problems with this solution:

1. I do not know the full set of columns at the time of writing this code. The table specification does change over time (the two tables are created by reading csv files, though the two tables to be compared are always identical). Is there a way to group by something like '*'?
2. If grouping is indeed possible in a way I described above, I would need to exclude the `src` value I have added to identify the table a resulting record comes from.

Comment: I guess ```EXCEPT``` or ```INTERSECT``` clause will help you

Comment: Sans using dynamic SQL, there is no way to articulate to SQL to select all columns except for one of them.

Comment: @PrasannaKumarJ neither `EXCEPT` nor `INTERSECT` is available in MySQL.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen would there be a way if I would skip the `src` part and compare all the existing columns?

Comment: You need to list all columns you want to group by on, but you can use dynamic sql to generate the list for you or use a script / program written in snother programming language to generate the sql dynamically for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your last edit makes it such a different question that it may be worth raising a new question and deleting this one that way some of the experienced contributors may revisit it.

Another approach would be to hash all the columns and compare the has values , you will still need to build the query from information_schema.columns but at least you don't need to match every column individually. Here's an example

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T,T1;
    
    CREATE TABLE T
    ( id INT, col1 INT, col2 VARCHAR(2));
    INSERT INTO T VALUES
    ( 22 , 1111 , 'gt'  ),
    ( 23 , 5624 , 'ha'  ),
    ( 24 , 7775 , 'oh'  ),
    ( 26 , 2113 , 'yh'  ),
    ( 28 , 9988 , 'wq'  );
    
    CREATE TABLE T1
    ( id INT, col1 INT, col2 VARCHAR(2));
    INSERT INTO T1 VALUES
    ( 22 , 1111 , 'gt'  ),
    ( 23 , 5624 , 'ha'  ),
    ( 25 , 3333 , 'er'  ),
    ( 26 , 2113 , 'ya'  ),
    ( 28 , 9988 , 'wq'  );
    
    SELECT T.ID,T.COL1,T.COL2,MD5(CONCAT(T.COL1,T.COL2)) MD5T,
                    T1.COL1,T1.COL2,MD5(CONCAT(T1.COL1,T1.COL2)) MD5T1
    FROM T
    LEFT JOIN T1 ON T1.ID = T.ID
    HAVING MD5T <> MD5T1 OR MD5T1 IS NULL
    UNION 
    SELECT T.ID,T.COL1,T.COL2,MD5(CONCAT(T.COL1,T.COL2)) MD5T,
                    T1.COL1,T1.COL2,MD5(CONCAT(T1.COL1,T1.COL2)) MD5T1
    FROM T1
    LEFT JOIN T ON T1.ID = T.ID
    WHERE T.ID IS NULL
    ;

+------+------+------+----------------------------------+------+------+----------------------------------+
| ID   | COL1 | COL2 | MD5T                             | COL1 | COL2 | MD5T1                            |
+------+------+------+----------------------------------+------+------+----------------------------------+
|   26 | 2113 | yh   | 0a67aa31e57d3b81e9a3adedcbf52926 | 2113 | ya   | bf963ac4282e4f16339a5f79d5042dcb |
|   24 | 7775 | oh   | fde0959e35d89f4ad2b0f8c0b89e4b20 | NULL | NULL | NULL                             |
| NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL                             | 3333 | er   | eb773ea6e5dd316a4e461ce4b52b1706 |
+------+------+------+----------------------------------+------+------+----------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.015 sec)
```

NB I don't know how this performs over a lot of columns but I guess there's scope for chunking the hash values.

Comment: My initial query with `GROUP BY col1, col2, ...` replaced by the actual list of columns (obtained with information_schema) gives me all I need (even without using the unique id). But I will give your approach a try as well. With around 100k records and between 30 and 60 columns it's worth to get an idea about the performance.

Answer (score 0):

if you know the source and can sum a value of 1 using a window function then by definition if the result is 1 then the missing source is obvious. for example

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T,T1,t2;

create table t(id int);

create table t1(id int);

insert into t values (1),(2),(3);

insert into t1 values (1),(4),(3);

create table t2 as
select *,'t' as src from t
union all
select *,'t1' from t1;

with cte as
(
select *,sum(1) over (partition by id) sumrows 
from t2
)
select *,
        case when src = 't' then 't1'
        else 't'
        end as 'missing' 
from cte
where sumrows = 1;

+------+-----+---------+---------+
| id   | src | sumrows | missing |
+------+-----+---------+---------+
|    2 | t   |       1 | t1      |
|    4 | t1  |       1 | t       |
+------+-----+---------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.013 sec)
```

in your case since you don't know all the columns you would need to use dynamic sql.

NB I have no idea how this would perform with a lot of columns and a lot of data and for illustration purposes I haven't attempted to optimise this process.

Also 'different in at least one field' isn't a goer but it may be if the result of the above process skins down the result set to a reasonable size.

Comment: Missing records are not the issue. I can identify them with my original query using a column with an unique id to group by. Dynamic sql doesn't seem to be avoidable to compare all fields of the records.

Comment: ?? where did unique id come from it's not mentioned in the question, do both tables have a unique id which is the same if row exists in both tables if so that;s a significant change to the question.

Comment: Please add representative sample data to the question.

Comment: @p-salmon I just edited and added an example.